# Mysql 8.0.3: function regexp_replace does not exist

Tags: mysql-8.0

New project uses `regexp_replace`, so i updated mysql installation to 8.0.3. But still feeling like nothing changed =)

Trivial query:

```
$ echo "select regexp_replace('a','.','z')" | mysql mysql
ERROR 1305 (42000) at line 1: FUNCTION mysql.regexp_replace does not exist
```

Version:

```
$ # mysqld --version
/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.3-rc-log for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

REGEXP_REPLACE function was released in version 8.0.4, so updating to 8.0.12 solved the problem.